# Problema con Procedure y Case

Tags: pascal

Quiero hacer un menú, es para un juego, para probar el `case` y `procedure`, pero no funciona. Este es el código:

```
Program Juego;
uses crt;

Procedure Menu;
var op:integer;
begin
    Writeln ('Seleccione una opcion') ;
    Writeln ('1-Informacion');
    Writeln ('2-Salir');
    Read(op);
    Case op of  
        1:Procedure Informacion ;
        2:Procedure Salir ;
        else Writeln('Seleccione una opcion del 1 al 2');
    end;
end;

Procedure Informacion;
begin
    Writeln('Desarrollado por:');
    Readln();
end;

Procedure Salir;
var s:integer;
begin
    Writeln('¿Esta seguro que desea salir?');
    Writeln('1-SI');
    Writeln('2-NO');
    Read(s);
    If s=1 then
        Halt(0);
    If s=0 then 
        Procedure Menu;
end;

begin
    Procedure Menu;
end.
```

**Este es el error que me da:**

> ```
> Juego.pas(11,13) Error: Illegal expression
> Juego.pas(12,2) Error: Constant Expression expected
> Juego.pas(12,2) Fatal: Syntax error, ":" expected but "ordinal const" found
> Fatal: Compilation aborted
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Llevo sin usar Pascal 17 años, pero si no recuerdo mal, el código tiene (al menos) dos problemas:

1. Cuando llamas a un procedimiento, no hace falta indicar que es un procedimiento, eso sólo se hace en la definición del mismo. Entonces, en lugar de hacer `Procedure Informacion` o `Procedure Salir`, deberías hacer `Informacion()` y `Salir()` respectivamente:

   ```
   Case op of  
       1: Informacion();
       2: Salir();
       else Writeln('Seleccione una opcion del 1 al 2');
   end;
   ```

   Y lo mismo para `Menu()` en el main.
2. No se puede llamar a una función/procedimiento que no se haya definido con anterioridad. En `Menu` estás llamando a `Informacion` y `Salir` que no se definen hasta después. La solución podría ser mover `Informacion` y `Salir` para que estén encima de `Menu`.

   Pero hay un problema: desde `Menu` llamas a `Salir` y desde `Salir` llamas a `Menu`... Con lo cual, no basta con simplemente mover las funciones de posición. Tienes que declarar las funciones de manera previa (*forward declaration*), esto se hace poniendo la cabecera de la función con la palabra reservada `forward` después, de este modo:

   ```
   procedure Informacion; forward;
   procedure Salir; forward;
   ```

   Podrías hacerlo también para Menu, pero como el procedimiento Menu se va a definir el primero, no hace falta.

Aplicando esos cambios, el código queda así y ya funciona ([como puedes ver aquí](http://rextester.com/NUNW90659)):

```
Program Juego;
uses crt;

procedure Informacion; forward;
procedure Salir; forward;

Procedure Menu;
var op:integer;
begin
    Writeln ('Seleccione una opcion') ;
    Writeln ('1-Informacion');
    Writeln ('2-Salir');
    Read(op);
    Case op of  
        1: Informacion();
        2: Salir();
        else Writeln('Seleccione una opcion del 1 al 2');
    end;
end;

Procedure Informacion;
begin
    Writeln('Desarrollado por:');
    Readln();
end;

Procedure Salir;
var s:integer;
begin
    Writeln('¿Esta seguro que desea salir?');
    Writeln('1-SI');
    Writeln('2-NO');
    Read(s);
    If s=1 then
        Halt(0);
    If s=0 then 
        Menu();
end;


begin
    Menu();
end.
```

Comment: Debo reconocer que he tenido que mirar online la declaración previa en Pascal porque no me acordaba cómo se hacía

Comment: ¿Se refiere a: procedure Informacion; forward; procedure Salir; forward; ? ¿Para que sirven esas declaraciones?y¿Por que no tiene que haber una tambien para menu?

Comment: @Enzo he editado la pregunta para responder a esas preguntas. La idea es que con `procedure Informacion; forward; procedure Salir; forward;` le estás diciendo al compilador que esas funciones están definidas más adelante (y de ese modo, aunque no esté definido el contenido, sí se podrá utilizar en otros procedimientos). Como el procedimiento Menu se va a definir el primero, no hace falta hacer una declaración previa (aunque podrías y funcionaría sin problemas).